# What are the real and imaginary parts of $(x+e^{ix})^{0.5}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Finding the real and imaginary parts of 
$(x+e^{ix})^{n}$ is easy if n is an integer greater than 1.  But what if n is a fraction?  Suppose I have a function  like $(x+e^{ix})^{0.5}$. How do you find the real and imaginary parts of this?

Edit: x is a real number...not complex.

Comment: Is $x$ a real number?

Comment: Assuming $x$ is real, let $(a+ib)^2=x+\cos x +i\sin x$... then evaluate $a,b$

Comment: which branch of the square root?

Answer (score 1):

Maple says
$$
\left({x+{{\rm e}^{ix}}}\right)^{1/2}=\frac{\sqrt {2\,\sqrt { \left( x+\cos \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{2}+ \left( \sin \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}}+2
\,x+2\,\cos \left( x \right) }}{2} 
\pm i \frac{\sqrt {2\,\sqrt { \left( x
+\cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+ \left( \sin \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{2}}-2\,x-2\,\cos \left( x \right) }}{2}
$$
where the sign depends on where $x+e^{ix}$ lies in the complex plane.

**note**
I prefer to write ${1/2}$ for the exponent, and not $0.5$.
I can then say that $1/2$ is an exact rational number, whereas $0.5$ is a real number rounded to the nearest tenth.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I wonder how Maple derived this.  I am wondering if the form is basically the same for (negative) powers of 2...1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 etc...

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is not an integer, $(x + e^{ix})^{n}$ is multi-valued.

First write $x + e^{ix} = x + \cos x + i\sin x = e^{i\theta} \sqrt{x^{2} + 2x \cos x + 1}$ for some real $\theta$ (unique up to an additive integer multiple of $2\pi$).

If $n$ is real, then
\begin{align*}
  (x + e^{ix})^{n}
  &= (x^{2} + 2x\cos x + 1)^{n/2} \exp(in\theta) \\
  &= \underbrace{(x^{2} + 2x\cos x + 1)^{n/2} \cos(n\theta)}_{\text{real part}} + i\underbrace{(x^{2} + 2x\cos x + 1)^{n/2} \sin(n\theta)}_{\text{imaginary part}}.
\end{align*}

Generally, letting $\ln$ denote the real branch of the natural logarithm,
\begin{align*}
  (x + e^{ix})^{n}
  &= (x + \cos x + i\sin x)^{n} \\
  &= \exp\bigl[n \log(x + \cos x + i\sin x)\bigr] \\
  &= \exp\bigl[n \bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}\ln(x^{2} + 2x \cos x + 1) + i\arg(x + \cos x + i\sin x)\bigr)\bigr] \\
  &= \exp\bigl[n \bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}\ln(x^{2} + 2x \cos x + 1) + i\theta\bigr)\bigr].
  \tag{1}
\end{align*}

To proceed, write $n = a + bi$ with $a$ and $b \neq 0$ real, multiply out the quantity in square brackets, and use $\exp(u + iv) = e^{u} \cos v + ie^{u} \sin v$ (for $u$ and $v$ real) to simplify (1) to your heart's content.

Comment: Super thankful for the input/feedback, but I'm not following you on a number of steps.  The first: could you outline how $x + \cos x + i\sin x = e^{i\theta} \sqrt{x^{2} + 1}$ for some real $\theta$ (unique up to an additive integer multiple of $2\pi$)'.

Comment: That's the "polar form" of a complex number: If $a$ and $b$ are real, there exists a real $\theta$ (unique up to an additive integer multiple of $2\pi$) such that $$a + bi = e^{i\theta}\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}\quad(= r e^{i\theta}).$$This may be more familiar as $a = r\cos\theta$ and $b = r\sin\theta$, with $r = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$.

Comment: My apology: I lost the term "$2x \cos x$" throughout. :S